# If the universe had a topological hole, would moving around the hole have a centripetal force?

Tags: topology, centripetal-force, geodesics

I understand that if it were of a toroidal topology, it would not literally mean that the universe is in the shape of a 3D donut. However, I can't seem to draw intuition on why or why not it may be the case that moving in a geodesic around the "hole" would have a centripetal force vector in some direction.

I'd be grateful if this could be explained at an undergrad-ish level.

Comment: Geodesic motion does not involve acceleration. The four-velocity just gets parallel-transported along the geodesic.

Answer (score 3):

When you say topological hole, the implication is that you're talking about a spacetime that can be made by taking some other spacetime and removing some points. For example, I can take Minkowski space, define $r$ as the distance from the $t$ axis, and remove all points with $r\le a$. Relativists are generally not interested in this kind of spacetime, and they would summarize their complaints by saying that this is not the *maximal extension* of this flat spacetime. That is, you could fill the hole back in, so removing it is artificial. GR doesn't make any prediction about this sort of thing. E.g., GR doesn't say what happens to an electron or an astronaut that reaches $r=a$.

A doughnut or torus topology does not have a hole in this sense. It's just the topology you get if you take a square and identify the left and right sides, and the top and bottom sides. It's like a video game such as PacMan, where going off one side of the screen takes you around. A topologist would say that the torus has a nonzero genus or a handle, but they wouldn't call it a hole.

For simplicity, let's consider a cylinder rather than a torus.

A particle performing geodesic motion on a spacetime with a cylindrical topology does not require a centripetal force to make it move that way. This is the definition of geodesic motion in GR: the motion of a particle that is not acted on by any force. The perceived need for a centripetal force only exists because we're imagining embedding the cylinder in a higher-dimensional space. There is no direction toward the axis, because there is no axis and no ambient space.

Although your example is a spacetime with a nontrivial topology, the same holds true for the kind of example that we more commonly care about in GR, which is a spacetime with a trivial topology but intrinsic curvature.